# python - remove header & footer from mvn dependency tree

Tags: python, maven, parsing, file-writing, dependency-tree

I need to take a maven dependency tree & remove the header & footer so that only the dependency info is left.  An example tree is below.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< brs:libadept >---------------------------
[INFO] Building libadept 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ libadept ---
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] brs:libadept:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.antlr:antlr4:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:58.2:compile
[INFO] +- brs:libutil8:jar:1.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.760 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-31T14:26:14-07:00
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

I have tried this so far:

```
import os
myCmd = 'mvn dependency:tree > new.txt'
os.system(myCmd)

fileObj = open("new.txt", "r")
fileOut = open("bulk.txt", "w")


def getBulk(text):
    for line in text.readlines():
        if line.startswith("[INFO] +- ") or line.startswith("[INFO] | ") or line.startswith("[INFO] \\\- ") or line.startswith("[INFO]    \\\- "):
            fileOut.write(line)
            return fileOut

print(getBulk(fileObj))
```

I want to be able to just get this info:

```
[INFO] +- org.antlr:antlr4:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:58.2:compile
[INFO] +- brs:libutil8:jar:1.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

But I am getting

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='bulk.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I have to make sure to take into account that the headers & footers might not always be the same number of lines (eg the lines starting with "[WARNING]" might not always be there, so I can't just write the program such that the first ten lines get deleted).
Thanks in advance!

Final answer:

```
import os
myCmd = 'mvn dependency:tree > new.txt'
os.system(myCmd)
fileObj = open("new.txt", "r").readlines()
fileOut = open("bulk.txt", "w")

def getBulk(text):
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith("[INFO] +- ") or line.startswith("[INFO] | ") or line.startswith("[INFO] \- ") or line.startswith("[INFO]    \- "):
            fileOut.write(line)
            print(line)
    return fileOut
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

mvn_dep_tree_cmd = 'mvn dependency:tree > new.txt'
os.system(mvn_dep_tree_cmd)

file_in = open("new.txt", "r")
file_out = open("bulk.txt", "w")

# flag denoting that current line is inside a tree
in_tree = False

for line in file_in.readlines():
    # this condition denotes the start of a tree
    if line.startswith("[INFO] +- "):
        in_tree = True
    if in_tree:
        # if we are inside a tree the following condition denotes end of the tree
        if line.strip() == '[INFO]':
            in_tree = False
            file_out.write('\n')
            file_out.write('\t<---------------------------------------------->')
            file_out.write('\n\n')
            print(line)
        else:
            # writing to the out file all the contents inside the tree
            file_out.write(line)
            print(line)

file_in.close()
file_out.close()
```